# How to check with for in list of hashes?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have file with multiple sets of data, as it:

```
metadata          :
mxRecords         :
name              : dev-dev
arecords          : {@{ipv4Address=127.0.0.1}, @{ipv4Address=127.0.0.2}, @{ipv4Address=127.0.0.3}, @{ipv4Address=127.0.0.4}}
```

I need find sets of data, where in arecords contains ipv4Address what I need.

How can I get access to values of ipv4Address?

Comment: You have nested custom objects rather than hash tables. If your output above is stored in `$obj`, then you can use `$obj.arecords.ipv4Address`.

Answer (score 1):

You have nested custom objects rather than hash tables. You can use the member access operator `.` to reference nested properties.

**Example 1: From one object, find the arecords object that contains the target IP address**

```
# Record example matching your post
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{
           metadata = ''
           mxRecords = ''
           name = 'dev-dev'
           arecords = [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.1'}, 
               [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.2'}, 
               [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.3'}, 
               [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.4'}
}
$targetIP = '127.0.0.3'
$obj.arecords | Where ipv4Address -eq $targetIP

# Output 
ipv4Address
-----------
127.0.0.3
```

**Example 2: From multiple objects, find the object that contains an arecords array with the target IP**

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{
           metadata = ''
           mxRecords = ''
           name = 'dev-dev'
           arecords = [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.1'}, 
               [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.2'}, 
               [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.3'},
               [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.4'}
},
[pscustomobject]@{
           metadata = ''
           mxRecords = ''
           name = 'prod-prod'
           arecords = [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.10'}, 
               [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.20'}, 
               [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.30'}, 
               [pscustomobject]@{ipv4Address='127.0.0.40'}
}
$targetIP = '127.0.0.10'
$obj | Where {$_.arecords.ipv4Address -contains $targetIP}

# Output
metadata mxRecords name      arecords
-------- --------- ----      --------
                   prod-prod {@{ipv4Address=127.0.0.10}, @{ipv4Address=127.0.0.20}, @{ipv4Address=127.0.0.30}, @{ipv4Address=127.0.0.40}}
```